# CORS con Golang desde React error 404

Tags: reactjs, cors, go, error404

alguien solucionó problemas de CORS en golang ? desde ya muchas gracias !!!
llamo al webserver Go con React en el puerto 3000:

```
const baseURL = 'http://localhost:8080/tasks';
    
    //
    const NewRecord ={
      Name: vName ,
      Content: vContent
    };
    let NewRecord2 = JSON.stringify( NewRecord ) ;

    const Config = {
      headers : { 
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json' ,
      }  ,
      responseType : 'json',
      withCredentials: false
    };

    // * DISPLAY 2 CHECK -----------------------------
    console.log( { baseURL, NewRecord2, Config } );
    

    // *  AXIOS POST: ----------------------------
    axios.post( {baseURL} , { NewRecord2 }, {Config})
    .then(res => {

      console.log('Respuesta >>>>>>', res);
      console.log(res.data.json);
      
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error:->> ', err  )
    }) ;
```

recibo este error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

mi webserver con golang :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(false) 
router.Use(JSON_Middleware)

fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./public/")) // Static Files.

// CORS 
    
c := cors.New(cors.Options{
  AllowedHeaders: ([]string{"X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Authorization"}),
  AllowedOrigins: []string{"*", "http://localhost/3000"},
  AllowedMethods: []string{http.MethodGet, http.MethodPost, http.MethodDelete, http.MethodPut, "OPTIONS"},
})

    

// 
router.Handle("/", fs) //
router.HandleFunc("/tasks", createTask).Methods("POST")        // r
//
fmt.Println("Escuchando puerto 8080 .")
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", c.Handler(router)))
```

---

*** EN EL DEBUGUER DEL NAVEGADOR:
*** En la consola puedo ver unos console.logs() que hice :

```
baseURL: "http://localhost:8080/tasks"
NewRecord2: "{"Name":"LLEVAR EL CARRO AL LAVADERO","Content":"luego del supermercado."}"
Config:
headers: {Content-Type: "application/json", Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*", Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS"}
responseType: "json"
withCredentials: false
```

*** En la pestaña Networks:

```
GENERAL:
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/[object%20Object]
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:3000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

RESPONSE HEADERS:
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 157
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Tue, 23 Jun 2020 14:11:51 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

REQUEST HEADERS:
POST /[object%20Object] HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 99
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Mobile Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: es-419,es;q=0.9

REQUEST PAYLOAD:
{NewRecord2: "{"Name":"LLEVAR EL CARRO AL LAVADERO","Content":"luego del supermercado."}"}
```

*** el programa usa el metodo GET para traer datos a una lista y si trabaja bien leyendo datos con axios desde la database. Pero Luego cuando debe hacer un POST recibe este error que supongo es de CORS. La app esta hecha con React js.

*** con el Postman si funciona el POST. el api en Go trabaja bien y si lo uso con postman graba el registro en la database.

Answer (score 0):

Tuve el mismo problema, mi forma de solucionarlo fue implementando un middleware que agrega las cabeceras necesarias para la verificación CORS.

Ejemplo, en este caso estoy habilitando CORS para los verbos GET y OPTIONS, options es necesario para que el navegador envie petición de verificación.

```
func commonMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    //Necessary for request cords
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, OPTIONS")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization")
    next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
})
```

}

Según [mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS), mi fuente de documentación favorita para este tema CORS:

> El estándar de Intercambio de Recursos de Origen Cruzado trabaja añadiendo nuevas cabeceras HTTP que permiten a los servidores describir el conjunto de orígenes que tienen permiso para leer la información usando un explorador web.  Adicionalmente, para métodos de solicitud HTTP que causan efectos secundarios en datos del usuario (y en particular, para otros métodos HTTP distintos a GET, o para la utilización de POST con algunos tipos MIME), la especificación sugiere que los exploradores "verifiquen" la solicitud, solicitando métodos soportados desde el servidor con un método de solicitud HTTP OPTIONS, y luego, con la "aprobación" del servidor, enviar la verdadera solicitud con el método de solicitud HTTP verdadero. Los servidores pueden también notificar a los clientes cuando sus "credenciales" (incluyendo Cookies y datos de autenticación HTTP) deben ser enviados con solicitudes.